# Elegant way to group conditionally enabled 'more detail' form fields depending on 'parent' fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm developing large form which has many groups of fields.  Each group will have a 'main' true/false dropdown/radio button field which upon being set true will enable the associated 'more details' fields in the group.

I understand that the usual way to do this is to bind JS on change handlers to the 'main' field of each group which will then enable / disable the 'more details' fields depending on the value of the 'main' fields

Since there are many of these groups, to manually bind the event handlers to each 'main' field seems time consuming and repetitive. Surely there is a better way.  How can I elegantly implement this functionality?  Imagine that the data-option attribute can be used for this effectively.

My pseudocode:

```
- On change event handler for all fields with data-group-parent
    - For all elements with data-group-child-of == this data-group-parent, set enabled value to
```

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really all comes down to how you want to build it, and how you want to drive it...

If you're just hiding or disabling large parts of a form, until their main switch is thrown, then you're saving a lot of that work.

```
<form id="MyForm">
    <section>
        <header>
            <p>I would like to experience the best yams the world has to offer!</p>
            <select data-switch="gourmet-yams-of-the-world">
                <option value="1">true</option>
                <option value="0">false</option>
            </select>
        </header>
        <div class="big-ol-list-of-yam-options"
             data-controller="gourmet-yams-of-the-world"
             hidden>
            <!-- ... -->
        </div>
    </section>
</form>
```

All you're really missing here is a single event-listener, a couple of lines of attribute-parsing, and some querySelector magic.

```
// listen for onchange, check if it's a "switch" that changed, and find the panel the switch controls

var isSwitch = function (el) { return el.hasAttribute("data-switch"); },
    getGroupName = function (el) { return el.getAttribute("data-switch"); },
    getGroup = function (root, groupName) {
        return root.querySelector("[data-controller=\"" + groupName + "\"]");
    },
    handleSwitch = function (evt) {
        var el = evt.target,
            switchEl = isSwitch(el),
            groupName, group, action;

        if (!switchEl) { return; }
        groupName = getGroupName(el);
        group = getGroup(MyForm, groupName);
        action = !!(+el.value); // converting it to a number (1 or 0, and then to Boolean)
        toggleGroup(group, action);
    };


MyForm.addEventListener("change", handleSwitch);
```

Mind you, this isn't guaranteed to work with all browsers.
Funnily, it's the browsers that don't support `addEventListener` that also have a hard time bubbling the "change" event.

There are other ways of doing this, as well.

Personally, I'd probably use a combination of this sort of event-handling, but build out the actual form using JSON metadata... ...just because.

Not the absolute fanciest solution in the world, not guaranteed to work if you're using ghettoIE (though a little jQuery could help that, I guess), and not configuration-driven -- you'd still end up constructing that HTML however you're currently doing it, but as for saving on the frustration of having hundreds of listeners all over the place, that would be a simple, blazing-fast solution, compared to the alternatives.

Comment: Great answer and thanks for the detailed code.

I wonder if it would be more efficient to do it this way using data-options or using classes instead, and bind the on change directly to the switch.

Comment: That all depends on what you intend to do. If you expect that all of them are going to be styled the exact-same way, then classes are fine as well. In terms of performance, unless you're talking about old IE (which doesn't allow bubbling on "change" events, or `addEventListener`, or `querySelector` anyway), then it does make a bit of a difference, but you can use `data-*` attributes all the way back to IE6. As for efficiency, that really depends. This way uses much less memory, as for the extra CPU, perhaps, but only if you expect users to go through hundreds of changes in seconds...

Answer (score 1):

jQuery work on sets of elements so ordinary using a very small amount of code you can affect many elements. Imagine you have following HTML:

```
Some info
<span class="more-details"></span>
<div class="more-info">
    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info
</div>
Some info
<span class="more-details">Click for more...</span>
<div class="more-info">
    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info
</div>Some info
<span class="more-details">Click for more...</span>
<div class="more-info">
    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info
</div>Some info
<span class="more-details">Click for more...</span>
<div class="more-info">
    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info    Some more info
</div>
```

It shows some info, then clickable element (note: you don't have to use radio/dropdown) and then some additional info. We want additional info to be hidden initially and only appear when user click the link:

```
$('.more-details').text('Click for more...');
$('.more-info').hide();
```

Once this is done you can attach a click event to all clickable elements via single function:

```
$('.more-details').click(function(){

    var $span = $(this);

    if ($span.text() == 'Click for more...') {
        $span.next().show();
        $span.text('Click for less...')
    } else {
        $span.next().hide();
        $span.text('Click for more...')
    }

})
```

**Take it for a spin: http://jsfiddle.net/Ckr85/**

You don't have to use data attributes - you can combine groups/elements by common class. And again, using a single link to "Show More/Less" is more user-friendly than radio/dropdowns.

Comment: Great answer - very simple.  I wonder which is more appropriate to use classes or custom data attributes?  Maybe a combination of both?

Comment: Ordinary data attributes are used just for that - to store data. You can use them as selectors, but classes are more common approach.